# Android Developer Guide Website Showing in Hindi

Tags: android, web

Recently, I always get a Hindi version of [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com). I don't remember making any changes myself. My location is in India, but I am just a student, I have no idea of their language, how do I fix this?

[image]

Check out sidebars and menus.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I Think Google Developer Guide allows only image displayed languages not hindi language in their website,so from where you get website in Hindi language?make sure no any Extension install in your browser for getting Hindi language website. and yes please check in another browser before any changes

Comment: It happens only on this website. Perhaps, it's Chinese. As I said, I have no knowledge of the language. I am adding a picture to the question

Comment: @ClintonYeboah where you get Hindi language..?there are something other lnaguage like chinese..

Comment: for change it by default language, scroll down up to last and check right corner there are option to change language and  from there you can change language to English

Comment: I was thinking its Hindi because am in India, and perhaps they are using my location to set my language. It can also be Chinese though

Comment: Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Yea, I found it!. Thanks though

Comment: always wc @ClintonYeboah